# EXcel Web Access - web part Error

Tags: excel-services, sharepoint-enterprise

I asked this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950282/open-excel-sheet-in-share-point-page-webpart-itself) in stack overflow, Hence this forum is dedicated for sharepoint, Thought to ask here!!

I got to know how to get the Excel using sharepoint Excel web access webpart. However I am getting an error "Excel Services is unable to process the request. Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again!!" Even If I directly access the Excel from the document library also getting the same error!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be nice if you could provide some log information, but double check:

- Excel Services is actually running on the farm.
- Check if you can run Get-SPExcelServiceApplication
- Check the Trusted File Location for Excel Services
- Check if your Web Application has a service connection to the Excel Services

Comment: Hi Andres thank you for your help, Please have a look at the updated answer, Finally got it worked!! Problem was Excel services web service application proxy is not available under the service connections. As updated in my answer I created a new Excel service so that the above proxy is available under the service connections of my web application. (as mentioned in my link). Since the actual problem was your first point I am selecting your answer as my solution, Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

At the end got it working, In order to get rid off the error we need to activate the **Excel services web service application proxy** in web application **service connections**.

In case the above mentioned proxy is not available under the service connections, go ahead and create one. Need some help, [its right here](http://www.stickyglue.co.za/index.php/archives/97/comment-page-1#comment-1921) !!

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this previously here ... If you need further clarification pls ping / comment. I believe your error is because it is missing the hotfix.

[Excel Services 2010 Error - "The workbook cannot be opened."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/excel-services-2010-error-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened/21842#21842)

Goodluck

Comment: Hi Aben got that worked, Please refer to my answer updated here, Thank you for spending time on this!!