# Excel Web Access Web Part won't display workbook

Tags: 2010, excel-services, office-web-apps

We've recently upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and we are trying to get the Excel Web Access web part to work.

Excel Services is running if that's required, the workbook location is configured to be trusted, and when linking a Workbook to the web part, this displays

[image]

The full message is below, even though a Workbook is selected.

> To display a workbook in this Web Part, you must first select the workbook.
>
> To select a workbook, open the tool pane, and then edit the Workbook property

**Question**: Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this?

It may be related, but if I try to open the Workbook in the Excel Web Access (not the web part) I receive this message.

[image]

I've tried to look this up and most things say to check permissions based on error messages, but there are no messages in the Event Viewer. This is similar to [Excel Services 2010 Error - "The workbook cannot be opened."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/excel-services-2010-error-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened) but none of the solutions work.

There is an Excel Services Proxy running and Office Web Apps is enabled on the site collection.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check that Excel Calculation Services is started. Central Admin > Application Management >Manage services on server

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that the excel is to complex for showing..

try a simple excel sheet and it will work

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE tdc. You could edit your answer, add additional info on what features of excel doesn't work. Is it lookup to other worksheets, calculations or other things that makes Excel Web App respond like this? Thank you!