# Excel Web access webpart url

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I am following an [Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/05/21/excel-services-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened.aspx) to solve a "The Workbook cannot be opened" that appears on my webpart when I load the document. It mentions getting the url of the webpart, in order to complete a powershell command. However I do not understand what url they mean and how to get it from that part. I also don't see a list of webparts in the central admin panel.

Comment: Have you tried following the answers found in [this other stack exchange question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/excel-services-2010-error-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened?rq=1)?

Comment: It doesn't say web part, it says web application. The URL is http://yourIntranetSite