# Cant open excel workbooks in browser sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, excel-services

Okai I am currently facing an error when i try to open excel files in browser .  it gives the prompt "The workbook can not be opened".

Upon checking the logs I found the following entries in the log file . recently we tried to move our site over https but later the idea was scrapped and we retracted to the old iis settings furthermore sharepoint forefront protection is also installed on our farm .

When i check the event viewer I see the following error every time i try to open excel workbook on sharepoint browser

1719104822: #960013: Antivirus scanner timed out.

**ULS LOGS :**

m   MossHostFileLoader.GetCloseUri: parent folder/list url = /CorporatePlanning/Tasweeq QAS/9 - Functional Procedures and Standards/Corporate Planning/Standards/Master documents for file = Tasweeq QAS/9 - Functional Procedures and Standards/Corporate Planning/Standards/Master documents/PLS-06A Sample Economic Template A (Condensates) 14 Aug 2013.xlsx    3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932

```
0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      5pam    Medium      BaseWorkbookManager.GetBaseWorkbookAndMarkUsedAsync: There are 1 Base Workbooks in the Base Workbook Manager    3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
```

0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      27e7    Medium      BaseWorkbookManager.GetBaseWorkbookAndMarkUsedAsync: Spawning BaseWorkbook job to load the file.    3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932

0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      gvr1    Medium      BaseWorkbook.CacheStream: Fetching `"http://tq-intra1:77/CorporatePlanning/Tasweeq%20QAS/9%20-%20Functional%20Procedures%20and%20Standards/Corporate%20Planning/Standards/Master%20documents/PLS-06A%20Sample%20Economic%20Template%20A%20(Condensates)%2014%20Aug%202013.xlsx"` to local disk cache as "C:\Windows\TEMP\Excel Server\FileCache\f85d573e-d592-4ce5-8c5e-3095a297861c\Workbooks\f1c8e29f-15fc-42a9-89bb-37c14a5995b0.xlsx.xlserver"  3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932

0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      d1qs    Medium      MossHostFileLoader.FetchStreamInternal: Fetching version 512 from File.Versions collection. The latest version available is: 512    3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932

**0x1868    SharePoint Foundation           General                         1   Critical    1719104822: #960013: Antivirus scanner timed out.   3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zq    Medium      BaseWorkbookManager.GetBaseWorkbookAndMarkUsedAsync: Got an error when trying to fetch file from file loader. Error was Id=GenericFileOpenError; Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.FileOpenException: The workbook cannot be opened. ---> Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.HostFileException ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Error Found:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStreamCore(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStream(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinaryStream()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStreamInternal()     --- End of inner ex... 3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zq    Medium      ...ception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStreamInternal()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStream(IIdentity currentIdentity)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.SharePointFileLoader.FetchStream()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.SharePointFileLoader.FetchStream()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbookManager.CacheStream(CachedFile cachedFile, FileLoader loader)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbook.Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ICachedFileProvider.SaveFile(CachedFile cachedFile)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Cached...  3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
0x1868  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zq    Medium      ...File.SaveFile(ICachedFileProvider fileProvider)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.LocalDiskCache.ReserveCachedFileAndMarkUsed(FileId fileId, ICachedFileProvider fileProvider, Boolean replaceExistingFile)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbook.ReserveCachedFileAndMarkUsed(FileLoader fileLoader)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbookManager.GetBaseWorkbookAndMarkUsedAsync(AsyncHandler`1 callback, Object userState, Request request, Uri uri, Boolean newWorkbook, Boolean useCollection, Boolean loadedOnDemand) 3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932**
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x1868  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=84.4791 3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      bbow    Medium      BaseWorkbook.LoadWorkbookJobAsync: Starting. FileId.Uri=http://tq-intra1:77/CorporatePlanning/Tasweeq%20QAS/9%20-%20Functional%20Procedures%20and%20Standards/Corporate%20Planning/Standards/Master%20documents/PLS-06A%20Sample%20Economic%20Template%20A%20(Condensates)%2014%20Aug%202013.xlsx   3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Job: LoadWorkbook  3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Document=http://tq-intra1:77/CorporatePlanning/Tasweeq%20QAS/9%20-%20Functional%20Procedures%20and%20Standards/Corporate%20Planning/Standards/Master%20documents/PLS-06A%20Sample%20Economic%20Template%20A%20(Condensates)%2014%20Aug%202013.xlsx  3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zp    Medium      BaseWorkbook.LoadWorkbookJobAsync: Detected error that occurred in the BeginXXX portion of this call. It will be wrapped and retheown. Error was Id=GenericFileOpenError; Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.FileOpenException: The workbook cannot be opened. ---> Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.HostFileException ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Error Found:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStreamCore(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStream(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinaryStream()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStreamInternal(... 3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92* w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zp    Medium      ...)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStreamInternal()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHostFileLoader.FetchStream(IIdentity currentIdentity)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.SharePointFileLoader.FetchStream()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.SharePointFileLoader.FetchStream()     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbookManager.CacheStream(CachedFile cachedFile, FileLoader loader)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbook.Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ICachedFileProvider.SaveFile(CachedFile cachedFile)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server...  3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92* w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      91zp    Medium      ....CalculationServer.CachedFile.SaveFile(ICachedFileProvider fileProvider)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.LocalDiskCache.ReserveCachedFileAndMarkUsed(FileId fileId, ICachedFileProvider fileProvider, Boolean replaceExistingFile)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbook.ReserveCachedFileAndMarkUsed(FileLoader fileLoader)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.BaseWorkbookManager.GetBaseWorkbookAndMarkUsedAsync(AsyncHandler`1 callback, Object userState, Request request, Uri uri, Boolean newWorkbook, Boolean useCollection, Boolean loadedOnDemand).   3f0aca0b-b7df-4ef2-8983-2ab3b35c9932
10/07/2014 11:30:06.92  w3wp.exe (0x0B70)                           0x0D10  Excel Services Application      Excel Calculation Services      8trf    Medium      BaseWorkbookManager.UnsafeRemoveWorkbook: There are 0 Base Workbooks in the Base Workbook Manager

Comment: Have you attempted the solution in [this related question?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/excel-services-2010-error-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened?rq=1)

Comment: my service account has db owner privilege on the content database the issue is not related to permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue. I just removed the **Document Library URL** from **Trusted File locations** and it worked. 
GoTo **Excel Services > Global Settings > Trusted file locations**
and remove the entry of document libraray you may have added.